# What is the default unit for QGIS scales and how do I set it to Km?

Tags: qgis, scale

I want to render a specific layer only between 0-12km but have no idea how to set it in QGIS because the scales dimensions are high numbers.
My project and layers CRS is EPSG:2039.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what the default is but this should help you set it to KM.

Check out:

http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Getting_Started_with_CRS_and_Projections

OR

Page 9 of http://wiki.osgeo.org/images/3/38/Db_foss_m1.pdf

"To set project properties click "[Settings > Project Properties]" in the main menu. The "Project Properties" window will appear. Click on the "[General]" tab and set Project Title and Map Units."

Answer (score 1):

The default for EPSG:2039 is meters (see http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2039/html/) so you'll need to divide the scale denominator by 1000 for Km.